AIDE project initialization shows up with errors
When I try to sync the project, I get:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 65

Caused by: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 65

Caused by: org.gradle.cache.CacheOpenException: Could not open cp_init generic class cache for initialization script '/data/data/com.itsaky.androidide/files/home/.androidide/init/init.gradle' (/data/data/com.itsaky.androidide/files/home/.gradle/caches/8.1.1/scripts/6qdjkb6rq0cppo2sendc74wks).

Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildActionFailureException: The supplied build action failed with an exception.

My build.gradle.kts is:
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "14.0.0" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "14.0.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "21.0.1" apply false
}


tasks.register<Delete>("clean") {
    delete(rootProject.buildDir)
}

I checked the java version on AIDE with termux and it said 21.0.1
My android version is 14 so the corresponding API would be 34 but I tried that (34.0.0 on com.android.application and com.android.library)
My gradle version is 8.1.1

Markdown Editing Help
